# Trying to grasp callbacks javascript

Tags: javascript

I am currently learning Javascript, and i am trying to grasp my head around callbacks. And there is something i am trying to understand.

What i do not understand is, how does the function in the click call get the value from the function sendData? I do understand that we always return an array, but how does the value become data?

```
// Function that takes callback
function sendData(callback) {
  
      let data = ['1', '2']; 
      // Here we return the sendData function, with  a array value

      return callback(data); 
}

 // Use the function when  the btn gets clicked
btn.addEventListener('click', (event) => { 


  // But how come the value here becomes the returned value?
  sendData(function (value)  { 
    console.log(value); // Outputs 1,2 in the console
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

> What i do not understand is, how does the function in the click call get the value from the function sendData?

First:

> ```
> sendData(function (value)  {
> ```

You call `sendData` and pass it a function as an argument.

The function you pass expects an argument which it will put in the `value` parameter.

Second:

> ```
> function sendData(callback) {
> ```

The argument you pass to `sendData` (the function above) gets assigned to the `callback` parameter.

Third:

> ```
> return callback(data);
> ```

You call `callback` (which is that function) and pass it one argument (`data`) which gets assigned to the first parameter (`value`).

---

> I do understand that we always return an array

You don't. `sendData` takes the return value of calling `callback(data)` and returns *that*.

It passes an array *into* `callback` but what it returns depends on what `callback` returns.

In this case, `callback` has no `return` statement at all, so it returns `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

When I was first starting out, one of the things that helped me intuitively grasp callbacks was moving code around.
This can be a bit tricky at first, but becomes second nature once you get the hang of it.

To demonstrate the idea, we can modify `sendData` in a way that it has no callback, but behaves the same way as it did before in this specific example.

```js
function sendData() {
    const data = ['1', '2'];

    const callback = function (value)  { 
        console.log(value);
    };

    return callback(data); 
}
```

All we've done in the above example is moved the callback from the function argument into an inlined variable, but the way the data is passed around is a lot clearer.

If you then unwrap the function since it's called right away after its declaration, the flow is more barebones:

```js
function sendData() {
    const value = ['1', '2'];
    console.log(value);
    return;
}
```

Note that I've renamed `data` to `value` so that it matches the name used for the callback argument.

Hope this mental model is useful, if perhaps complementary to [Quentin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64703279/1470607).